# AWS SES Exception Handler - too many exceptions - error too long

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, exception, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES for sending emails, my final sending code being

```
try {
                         $result = $sesClient->sendEmail($email);                           
                         $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
                         $result['success'] = $messageId;
                    } catch (Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException $e) {           

                        $result['error'] = $e;
                    }
```

At the end of my query loop I want to gather all the errors and having them sent by email, but the problem is that only one error has about 7000 characters and that is because either if I catch Exception or Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException, I also get information from GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException'  and many other infos which I do not realy need. Is there any way I can restrict the message with the main error message, which, in my case, was using an email with no @domain.com attached.

Answer (score -1):

```
} catch (Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException $e) {           

                        $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
```